# How to compare columns of a 2d array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

```
[0][0]
[0][1]
[1][0]
[1][2]
```

If I loop through the array, the code should identify the values that are the same in column 1 and then return the difference of the corresponding values in column 0.

For example, the answer for looping through the 1st column should be 1 because 1 - 0 = 1;

This is my code so far.

```
        int l1temp = 0;
        int l2temp = 0;
        int l1 = 0;
        int l2 = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                if(arr[i][1]== arr[j][1]) {         
                    l1temp = Math.abs(arr[i][0] - arr[j][0]);
                    System.out.println(l1temp);
                    if(l1temp > l1) {
                        l1 = l1temp;
                    }
                }
                if(arr[i][0] == arr[j][0]) {
                    l2temp = Math.abs(arr[i][1] - arr[j][1]);
                    //System.out.println(l2temp);
                    if(l2temp > l2) {
                        l2 = l2temp;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Post the code what you have already tried.

Comment: I have added it

Comment: If your Array will always be Nx2 dimensionally, you dont need two for loops. Also its not clear what you actually want here. I am guessing you need the max difference between a[i][0] and a[i][1]?